# Updating $scope variable after push message from websocket server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a connection to a websocket server that pushes messages to my angularJS App. I receive those messages in a service and now I want to public this data on the gui.

```
angular.module("test", [])
   .value("DATA", [])
   .service("WSS", ["$rootScope", "DATA", function ($rootScope, DATA) {

       //initialise websocket here

       m_WebSocket.onmessage = function (msg) {
           $rootScope.$apply(function () {
               DATA = angular.fromJson(msg.data).slice();
           });

           console.debug(DATA); //gives me the expected result
       };
   }])
   .controller("CTRL", ["$scope", "DATA", function ($scope, DATA) {
       $scope.data = DATA;//wont update
   }]);
```

So, as far as I have understood angular I thought it must work this way but my DATA Array stays empty. What am I missing here?

Comment: A few things, try to *very* sparingly use `$rootcope`, there's almost always a better way. Also, you shouldn't be doing anything with a `$scope` of any kind within a service. Only controllers/directives access $scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign `DATA = angular.fromJson(msg.data).slice();` it doesn't affect `$scope.data = DATA;` at all, because `$scope.data` and new `DATA` array in service are not connected, they point to different objects. We say that *there is no reference between them*. So it won't update in view also.

It's very easy to fix if you just change a *property* of the object instead of overriding object reference entirely:

```
angular.module("test", [])
    .value("DATA", {values: []})
    .service("WSS", ["$rootScope", "DATA", function ($rootScope, DATA) {

    //initialise websocket here

    m_WebSocket.onmessage = function (msg) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            DATA.values = angular.fromJson(msg.data).slice();
        });
    };
}])

.controller("CTRL", ["$scope", "DATA", function ($scope, DATA) {
    $scope.data = DATA;
}]);
```

And then in template you would use  `data.values` instead of just `data` like you did before.

In this case `$scope.data` is an object which has property `values`. When new message comes from the server, the only thing that changes is property `values` of the `DATA` object. But in controller `$scope.data` points to **the same** object, hence Angular will be able to pick up chose new data.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to solve my problem :) But is it bad practice to use $rootScope for this case or what would be a better way to achive this?

Comment: You need to trigger digest anyway somehow. One way is to use $apply on the scope. So you have to use $rootScope, because you don't have controller scope anyway. Other option is to use $timeout service `$timeout(function () { DATA.values = angular.fromJson(msg.data).slice(); });`

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in using $timeout over $rootScope?

Comment: Well `$timeout` calls `$rootScope.$apply` internally, so.. The code is a bit cleaner, but still the fact is that you need to trigger digest and you don't have many options. I would continue using `$rootScope.$apply`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for it :)